# Recent experimental demonstrations of variational quantum algorithms?

Tags: resource-request, vqe, optimization, qaoa, variational-quantum-algorithms

I am interested in the recent experimental demonstrations of variational quantum algorithms.

Can someone please provide me with a list of references of recent experimental demonstrations of variational quantum algorithms, such as the variational quantum eigensolver (VQE), the quantum approximate optimization algorithm (QAOA) and quantum neural networks (QNNs)?

I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations on where to find more information about the current state of the art in variational quantum algorithms. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't know if you'd consider it "recent", but https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.09265 is a pretty nice review with plenty of references

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that this is a rapidly changing field, here is a list of some of the interesting recent QAOA experiments that I am aware of (in no particular order, slightly chronologically). Also, this list does not include papers which show interesting analytical or numerical evidence for QAOA, since that introduces a very large number of additional papers. In other words, these papers show quantum computing hardware QAOA demonstrations. Also, I am only including strictly QAOA papers - so for example this list does not include analog quantum computation results for sampling combinatorial optimization problems.

- https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.14427
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.03238
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.02064
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.00520
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04197
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02700